# CLLocationManager - returns wrong speed

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am trying to calculate users current driving speed, but there is a huge difference between cllocationmanager speed and actual driving speed.

As I am driving at 50 kmph and cllocation manager shows ~72/~73 kmph. Below is the code I am using.

```
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 1.0
        locationManager.headingFilter = 0.1
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

And below is the location manager protocol

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    let speedInKmph = location.speed * 3.6
    if speedInKmph > 10 {
        MyRide.shared.speedInfo.append(SpeedInfo(speed: speedInKmph))
        self.view.showToast("\(speedInKmph)  **********", position: .bottom, popTime: 2.0, dismissOnTap: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: where you get this `location.speed` , i tink you need to use `manager.location?.speed`

Comment: It's the last object from locations array. locations: [CLLocation].

Comment: or else see this for example : https://github.com/cdzombak/speed-ios/blob/master/Speed/SpeedTracker.swift

Answer (score 0):

@Anand, the CLLocationManager could be obtaining speed on one of two ways:

1. measuring the distance between two lat/long/alt triplets and dividing by some sort of time reference
2. using the native Doppler speed measurement on the GPS chip. Doppler speed is computed for all of the satellites that the particular GPS chip sees. Maybe Apple publishes the names and model numbers of the GPS chips inside of iPhones, I don't know.

I don't know which technique is used by CLLocationManager.

I think you have to test your system at a couple of speeds and three directions (due north, due east, and 45 degrees angle to due North and due East).

If all measurements show the same fudge factor of 1.45, you are probably good to go with:

```
let speedInKmph = location.speed * 3.6 * (1/1.45)
```

If your measurements don't match each other, then more studying required. If I figure it out I will post it here. The linked youtube might be a good idea.